# How can I find out who is explicitly invoking the garbage collector?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, galaxy

Running on a Samsung Galaxy S3 where ActivityManager.getMemoryClass() returns a healthy 64 (MB) of allowed heap space, I am getting numerous LogCat messages like this.

> WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
>   GC_EXPLICIT freed 267K, 35% free 15885/24327K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 52ms

The app loads caches about 100 contact thumbnails in memory and these GC calls are happening during the contact/bitmap loads. The result of the GC calls is stuttery performance when scrolling a listview.

I never call `System.gc()`.

My question is this. I thought `GC_EXPLICIT` log messages showed up only when the GC is being explicitly invoked (i.e. the Android memory manager isn't running the GC, some app-level code is doing so).

How do I find out who is explicitly invoking the GC so I can get a better handle on how to fix my code? *NOTE: I am aware that the Android memory manager can and will invoke the GC. My understanding is that results in `GC_CONCURRENT` calls, not `GC_EXPLICIT` calls.*

**UPDATE: Here's the code that loads the contact thumbnails. It runs on a background thread.**

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromContentUri(
    ContentResolver resolver,
    Uri uri
)
{
    InputStream is = null;
    Bitmap result = null;
    try
    {
        is = resolver.openInputStream(uri);
        result = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.e(
            TAG,
            "Failed to load photo for Uri " + uri + ": " + e.getMessage() 
        );
    }
    finally
    {
        if (null != is)
        {
            try
            {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            { }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: the system automatically call GC when low on memory

Comment: GC Calls generally don't cause stuttering.. What is most likely causing stuttering is the method in which you are loading the bitmaps themselves.. Can you post the code where you are loading the images?

Comment: its called automatically by JVM, when some UN-reachable objects are there... System.gc() does not make sure that garbage collector called, it is 100% depends on JVM,

Comment: Thanks for the comments all. Two points of clarification:

Comment: Thanks for the comments all. Two points of clarification:

1) The system's automatic calls are `GC_CONCURRENT`. I'm asking about _`GC_EXPLICIT`_.

2) @Vinay, those bitmaps are being loaded on a background thread. I don't think it is the cause in and of itself. I'm getting 5-7 `GC_EXPLICIT` calls each taking between 50-200ms and I'm decently confident that's where the stuttering is coming from... I will post the code in an edit, however.

Comment: What threading method are you using? If you are using new Thread(Runnable), then it will cause a GC_EXPLICIT call whenever the thread ends.. On Android, for operations like these, you should be using a Thread Pool Executor instead.